# is it possible to get records from mysql like January to March(2019) , April to June(2018) Below table etc

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table and want to get record like January to March(2019) , April to June(2018) etc

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(month,' to ',month,' (',year,')') AS quater_list 
FROM month_year GROUP BY month;
```

[image]

expect out should be January to March(2019) , April to June(2018)... etc

Comment: you might be able to fudge around using the `quarter()` function from `mySQL` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: see the table structure i have , i want the result from that table

Comment: @boy108zon Please check my answer once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query you are looking for

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MIN(number1), '%m')),' to ',MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MAX(number1), '%m')),' (',MAX(YEAR),')') temp,
CONCAT(YEAR,'-',number1,'-','01') temp1,
QUARTER(CONCAT(YEAR,'-',number1,'-','01')) qtr 
FROM new_table
GROUP BY qtr
```

[STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) - This is the inverse of the DATE_FORMAT() function. It takes a string str and a format string.

**Syntax**

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');
        -> '2013-05-01'
```

[MONTHNAME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) - Returns the full name of the month for date. The language used for the name is controlled by the value of the lc_time_names system variable ([Section 10.15, “MySQL Server Locale Support”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/locale-support.html)).

[QUARTER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter) - Returns the quarter of the year for date, in the range 1 to 4.

**Syntax:**

```
mysql> SELECT QUARTER('2008-04-01');
        -> 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable explanation